# How to add CEF to project as a lib?

Tags: c++, dll, dynamic-linking, chromium-embedded

I have searched a lot, have read official CEF support forum, but nothing there (and also here, on Stack) helped me to solve it

What I'm trying to do: I'm trying to implement CEF on my app (to make this question simpler, I will include code sample of empty ConsoleApplication project, because this error occurs there too), but I stucked with strange error which I can't figure out how to fix.

What I had done to achieve this error:

1. I downloaded CEF binary for Windows x64 from official [CDN](https://cef-builds.spotifycdn.com/) and generated `.sln` using `cmake -G "Visual Studio 16"`
2. I built `libcef_dll_wrapper` and successfully run `cefsimple` distributed with CEF.
3. I created my custom ConsoleApplication1 (code sample will be available below), linked `Debug/libcef.lib` from root of CEF binary folder and `libcef_dll_wrapper/Debug/libcef_dll_wrapper.lib` into my project.
4. I tried to compile the code

Once I did it, I got the following linker errors ("unresolved external symbol"):

```cpp
Error LNK2019   ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ _cef_string_utf16_clear в функции "public: static void __cdecl CefSettingsTraits::clear(struct _cef_settings_t *)" (?clear@CefSettingsTraits@@SAXPAU_cef_settings_t@@@Z).    ConsoleApplication1 C:\Users\User\source\repos\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1.obj  1   

Error LNK2019   ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "bool __cdecl CefInitialize(class CefMainArgs const &,class CefStructBase<struct CefSettingsTraits> const &,class scoped_refptr<class CefApp>,void *)" (?CefInitialize@@YA_NABVCefMainArgs@@ABV?$CefStructBase@UCefSettingsTraits@@@@V?$scoped_refptr@VCefApp@@@@PAX@Z) в функции _main. ConsoleApplication1 C:\Users\User\source\repos\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1.obj  1
```

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#include "include/cef_app.h"

using namespace std;

#pragma comment(lib, "C:/Games/cef/cef_binary_90.5.9+gd330790+chromium-90.0.4430.85_windows64/Debug/libcef.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "C:/Games/cef/cef_binary_90.5.9+gd330790+chromium-90.0.4430.85_windows64/libcef_dll_wrapper/Debug/libcef_dll_wrapper.lib")

int main()
{
    CefMainArgs args;
    CefSettings settings;

    CefInitialize(args, settings, nullptr, nullptr);
}
```

I'm using `Visual Studio 2019` to work with this.

Hope to get help and appreciate any comments/answers.
Have a great day/night!

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out.

On my case I had to clone [cef-project](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef-project/) instead of direct download from CEF CDN and init it using CMAKE (using examples provided in the repo), then I added my already created project into `cef-project` solution and it finally worked.